# How to make list entry of many paragraphs?

Tags: support, markdown

- List item

can be 1 line long only, right?

Comment: @return No he can't. He needs at least 10 rep to do that. The sandbox is protected.

Comment: @Antony Ouch...

Comment: -1 for the offensive comment plus it's really easy to click the question mark next to the editor toolbar and find the answer yourself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't see any offensive comments here.

Comment: @AndersonGreen because it's deleted now. Something about the fact the sandbox is protected.

Answer (score 8):

No, list items can span multiple paragraphs:

- Just start a bullet

  and keep indenting the following paragraphs with at least one space.
- New bullets can follow.

  - Nested bullets are the same.

    Just match the indentation of the first line past the bullet.

Markdown source of the above:

```
* Just start a bullet

 and keep indenting the following paragraphs with at least one space.

* New bullets can follow.

   * Nested bullets are the same.

     Just match the indentation of the first line past the bullet.
```

This is all documented with examples in the [original Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics).

Comment: So I must change every paragraph? No [][/] code?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Do I have to ident every paragraph or can I just wrap a tag around the text?

Comment: You indent every paragraph. You can use HTML too, see the specification I linked to and the formatting help in the editor.